# Autodesk Forge Viewer v7 - setThemingColor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I hope somebody can help me with a question about the setThemingColor function for the Autodesk Forge Viewer.

Basically my issue is that when I run the

`viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, new Vector4( 1, 1, 1, 1 ), null, true )`

from within my code nothing happens, and the element does not get a new color.

What I have tried:

1) If I try to run exactly the same line of code in the browser on the NOP_VIEWER it works, but only if it is a new dbId and not the one which had just been run from within my code.

2) I have tried to make sure to find the leaf dbId and use this. Did not have any effect.

3) I have tried to add the model to the function call:

`viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, new Vector4( 1, 1, 1, 1 ), model, true )`

4) I have tried to run the function on the level of the model:

`model.setThemingColor(dbId, new Vector4( 1, 1, 1, 1 ));`

`viewer.impl.invalidate(true);`

5) I have from within my code tested `viewer.isolate(dbId)` to make sure I have access to the viewer instance. And this works.

Is anybody else experiencing the same issue or can replicate the bug?
I hope somebody can help us out.

**EDIT: More infor after Petr Broz answer:**

"What version of the viewer are you using?": We are using v. 7.*

"Do you see any error logs in the console after setting the theming color?": I see no error logs.

"At what point in time are you trying to set the color (for example, after the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`)?": I use a onClick event on button, so it is after `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`

**ANSWER:**

I found the solution. I had to import THREE as a global.

`/* global THREE */`

instead of

`import {Vector4d} from "three"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick codepen setting the theming color on a pre-configured dbID (roof of the house), using viewer version 7.* (currently 7.10): https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/WNbYXWz.

It'd be helpful if we had some additional info, for example:

- What version of the viewer are you using?
- Do you see any error logs in the console after setting the theming color?
- At what point in time are you trying to set the color (for example, after the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`)?

Alternatively, if you don't mind sharing a live link to your app or your Forge app config, please send us an email to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we'll investigate the issue from our end.

Comment: "What version of the viewer are you using?": We are using v. 7.*


"Do you see any error logs in the console after setting the theming color?": I see no error logs.


"At what point in time are you trying to set the color (for example, after the GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT)?": I use a onClick event on button, so it is after GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT

Comment: If you can't share a link to a live app, could you post a snippet of the code where you're setting the theming color?

Comment: I am working on getting a version up and running live. And I will share it with you a bit later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a solution. See above ... Thanks for you help. :)